# Calculating the adjusted rand index?

Tags: clustering

I'm really close to understanding the adjusted rand index, but I lack a background in formal maths and I'm struggling to grasp one or two things.

I've been using the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index#Adjusted_Rand_index) page primarily. I've calculated the rand index for some pretend data.

The only part I'm struggling with is calculating *nij*, *ai* and *bj*. Am I adding every occurrence of them together? Or a singular row? A singular row wouldn't give the adjusted rand index would it?

Say I have two sets with two pairs in common between them, the total value of *bj* is going to be two, the total value of *ai* is also going to be two and *nij* is also two. This doesn't seem right for them all to be the same value?

Here's an example contingency table.

```
     x1    x2    x3
y1   0     0     0
y2   0     1     0
y3   0     1     0
```

I get that I sum these up to make *ai* or *bj*, but I think I must be calculating it wrong?

Comment: On this contingency table, Rand index is not well-defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically:

- n<sub>ij</sub> is across the diagonal (i.e., when i = j)
- a<sub>i</sub> is the row sums
- b<sub>j</sub> is the column sums

Using wikipedia, we have the formula:

$ARI = \frac{ \sum_{ij} \binom{n_{ij}}{2} - [\sum_i \binom{a_i}{2} \sum_j \binom{b_j}{2}] / \binom{n}{2} }{ \frac{1}{2} [\sum_i \binom{a_i}{2} + \sum_j \binom{b_j}{2}] - [\sum_i \binom{a_i}{2} \sum_j \binom{b_j}{2}] / \binom{n}{2} }$

Let's assume we have the table:

```
       x1    x2    x3    Sums
y1     1     1     0      2
y2     1     2     1      4
y3     0     0     4      4
Sums   2     3     5
```

Breaking into components:

- $\sum_{ij} \binom{n_{ij}}{2}  = \binom{1}{2} + \binom{2}{2} + \binom{4}{2} = 7$
- $\sum_i \binom{a_i}{2} = \binom{2}{2} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{2} = 13$
- $\sum_j \binom{b_j}{2} = \binom{2}{2} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{5}{2} = 14$

So, then

$ARI = \frac{7 - 13*14/45}{(13 + 14)/2 - 13*14/45} = 0.313$

Confirming this result in R:

```
library(cluster)

x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
y <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
adjustedRandIndex(x, y) # .313
```

Comment: The sum over i,j in `n_{ij}` is not only across the diagonal, but across the entire matrix. Thus a sum over ALL entries `i` and `j` choose n.

Comment: Permutations should lead to the same ARI (if you would use the diagonal entries only this symmetry would be lost).

Answer (score 1):

The answer by dmartin is nice to get some insight. To actually have a few lines of code (in `octave`/`matlab`):

```
function [RI ARI] = adjustedrandindex(A)                                                                                

    N=sum(sum(A));                                                                                                      
    R=sum(A,2);                                                                                                         
    C=sum(A,1);                                                                                                         

    a=sum(sum(bincoeff(A,2)));                                                                                          
    b0=sum(bincoeff(R,2));                                                                                              
    b=b0 - a;                                                                                                           
    c0=sum(bincoeff(C,2));                                                                                              
    c=c0 - a;                                                                                                           
    S=bincoeff(N,2);                                                                                                    
    d=S - (a + b + c);                                                                                                  

    RI=(a+d)/S;                                                                                                         

    ARI=(a-b0*c0/S)/((b0+c0)/2-b0*c0/S);                                                                                
end
```

Copyrights hereby: public domain.

```
B =

   1   1   0
   1   2   1
   0   0   4

[RI ARI] = adjustedrandindex(B)
RI =  0.71111
ARI =  0.31257
```

Permutations of B should lead to the same RI and ARI:

```
[RI ARI] = adjustedrandindex(B(:,randperm(size(B,2))))
RI =  0.71111
ARI =  0.31257
```